# Change default GPO namespace?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

We have recently set up a test domain controller to examine settings before pushing them to production at work.

Upon setting up this domain a simple error was made in the DNS settings. We forgot the subdomain.

`testdomain.com` rather than `site1.testdomain.com`.

We found a way to change a majority of the references, but Group Policy objects are not being applied correctly.

When running `RSOP.msc`. we get an error: `RSoP data is invalid` `Invalid namespace`

Did a bit of digging and it seems when we create a group policy, and click edit, the name does not reflect the servers FQDN.

`dc01.testdomain.com` rather than `dc01.site1.testdomain.com`.

How can we change this name space? or will we be forced to reset and re-run `dcpromo.exe` and ensure correct settings this time?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem.

We renamed our domain using `rendom.exe`, which changed settings in the forest. And then removed to `testdomain.com` zone in the DNS settings.

However! We failed to change the domain on the **domain controllers DNS suffix** through the system properties (System Properties > Advanced System Settings > Computer Name > "To rename this computer..." > "More..." > Change DNS there)

It's funny, here, how you seem to find the answer to your question right after you ask it.